# Replacing URL path parameters in java

Tags: java, rest, url, replace

I need to make a restful web service call to a service with URL path parameters

```
http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/user/get-user-by-email-address/company-id/{company-id}/email-address/{email-address}
```

What should be the best practice/efficient manner to replace the params with arguments while making service call?

Comment: well its obvious to replace the argument strings with actual values. There's no such good or bad practice.

Comment: Well,I was looking for something specific to Rest to perform this operation in the most efficient manner

Comment: *something specific to Rest* What do you mean? REST is not about replacing URL path parameters.

Comment: Thanks for clarity.Got your point!

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace multiple strings within a string,finally used

```
        import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringUtil;

        String[] searchList={"{company-id}","{email-address}"};
        String[] replList={groupId,userEmail};
        url=StringUtil.replace(url, searchList, replList);
```

Here `StringUtil` is a part of portal lib while a similar class `StringUtils` can also be used,which is part of Apache Commons library.